# Comparing 2 MySQL tables and grabbing the difference

Tags: mysql, database, comparison, inner-join

Okay, so I cannot figure out how to tell MySQL to take the difference of 2 values in 2 different tables if they share the same ID, which is then stored into another table. I attempted by using this snippet that should have kept any values with the same ID, but I guess I did it wrong:

```
SELECT tableA.itemid FROM tableA INNER JOIN tableB ON tableA.itemid=tableB.itemid WHERE tableA.price <> tableB.price;
```

tableA:

```
 itemid   |   price
   0      |     10
   1      |     40
   2      |     30
```

tableB:

```
 itemid   |   price
   0      |     40
   2      |     20
   3      |     90
```

(tableA-tableB) newTable:

```
 itemid   |   price
   0      |    -30
   2      |     10
```

If someone could help point me towards the right direction, that would be great. I'm still rather new to MySQL, so if I could also get some links to a few tutorials that deal with similar issues, that would also be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is almost there.  You just need to add an expression to the SELECT list. That expression will calculate the value you want to return as a column.

```
 SELECT a.itemid
      , a.price
      , b.price
      , a.price - b.price AS price_diff
   FROM tableA a 
   JOIN tableB b 
     ON b.itemid = a.itemid
  WHERE b.price <> a.price;
```

In this case, it's a fairly simple expression:

```
 a.price - b.price
```

With that, MySQL will subtract the value of the price column from tableB from the value of the price column in tableA. And return the result as a column in the result set.  Adding an alias to the column  "AS price_diff" will give the column in the resultset the specified name.

You can remove expressions from the SELECT list. The extra columns are added as a way to see what's happeing. To get just the two columns you want returned.

```
 SELECT a.itemid
      , a.price - b.price AS diff
   FROM ...
```

If you to take that resultset and store it as another table (I don't think you really want to do this) but it is possible to do that.

```
CREATE TABLE new_foo
AS
SELECT a.itemid
     , a.price - b.price AS diff
  FROM ...
```

Ideally, we'd modify that to identify a primary key, and the datatypes of the columns, etc.

```
CREATE TABLE new_foo
( itemid      BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
, price_diff  DECIMAL(20,2)   COMMENT 'difference in price'
) ENGINE=InnoDB 
AS
SELECT a.itemid          AS itemid
     , a.price - b.price AS price_diff
  FROM ...
```

Comment: For the first example, you said that it will return as a column. Do you know where it returns to exactly? I know you said it returns in the result set.. but I'm not really sure if it's added onto tableA or tableB.

Comment: The successful execution of a SELECT statement prepares a resultset and returns it to the client. If you are running the msyql command line client, the rows from the resultset are displayed in the terminal window.  The resultset from a query looks like a table... defined columns (with a name and a datatype) containing rows. (A SELECT statement can specify an ORDER BY clause, so that the rows are returned in a particular sequence, unlike a table.) The resultset is only retained for the duration of the statement. A SELECT statement doesn't remove or replace any values stored in the tables.

Comment: In the CREATE TABLE examples, I demonstrated how the rows returned from a SELECT query (a resultset) can be turned into a table. (It's effectively the same as running a CREATE TABLE and an INSERT ... SELECT statement.)  It's the CREATE TABLE AS or the INSERT that stores the resultset.  The SELECT is just providing the rows.

Comment: Oh, okay. That makes sense now. Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Hmm.. not sure why, but the new table disliked the defining of the table from the last example. Along with that, the "AS" right after the table creation isn't needed. However, when I ran the snippet, it took 1,500 IDs from tableA and somehow created roughly 14,000 IDs in the new table. Not really sure why that is.

Comment: In MySQL, the `AS` keyword is optional in that context. You are right. It isn't needed. But I think it helps the human reader recognize that those two parts are combined together (since both CREATE TABLE and SELECT stand as valid statements by themselves. It makes it more clear (to the human reader) that it's not just an inadvertent missing semicolon between two statements.

Comment: EDIT: Nevermind, I forgot that IDs can be repeated in a table. That can be sorted shortly. Again, thank you very much for the help!

Comment: The CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT ... statement takes *all* of the rows returned by the SELECT and inserts them into the new table.  If you are getting more rows than you expect, then likely you have "duplicate" matching itemid values. If there are four rows in TableA with itemid=7 and six rows in tableB with itemid=7, the query will return 24 rows with a.itemid=7.  Each of the four rows from tableA will be matched to each of the six rows from tableB.

Comment: Yea, I noticed that. I sort of forgot that IDs could be repeated in a table. I just sort of had a brain fart from that. Thank you for the detailed explanations of everything. Do you mind if I ask where or how you learned MySQL?

Comment: I've been working with MySQL on and off since 2002, back with version 3.23. That was the earliest I worked with it. Before that, it was relational databases Oracle (since v7), Teradata, DB2, DB2/2 (does anyone still remember OS/2?), Sybase (before it became SQL Server). Most of my work now is with MySQL, SQL Server, and Oracle. (And a smattering of Teradata, when we need to do an extract. I don't mention PostgreSQL because I've only experimented and am not as well versed.) And back before relational databases, it was IMS, VSAM and DBASE III (yeah, I've been at this a _long_ time.)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I cant add a comment, so If I assume your itemId is unique.
Try this query sql;)

```
SELECT a.itemid, a.price - b.price AS price
FROM tableA a, tableB b
WHERE a.itemid = b.itemid
```